# C++ dependency injection with fruit

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, google-fruit

I have class A and interface IInterface.
I need to inject 2 members IInterface into A.

So:

```
class A {
    IInterface* i1;
    IInterface* i2;
};
```

Can I inject 2 members (i1 and i2) into A using fruit DI framework?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers?

Comment: Nope, I have Googled a lot of examples and checked their github

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the Fruit author (thanks Alan for pointing me to this thread!).
The simplest way to inject that class would be constructor injection. Assuming that the two interfaces are the same (as in your example) and you want 2 different instances, you could use annotated injection, which would look like:

```
using namespace fruit;

struct FirstI {};
struct SecondI {};

class A {
    IInterface* i1;
    IInterface* i2;
public:
    INJECT(A(ANNOTATED( FirstI, IInterface*) i1, 
             ANNOTATED(SecondI, IInterface*) i2))
    : i1(i1), i2(i2) {}
};
```

In your `get*Component()` function you will then have to bind both (to the same type, or different types, the two are completely independent since they have different annotations):

```
class FirstIImpl : public IInterface {
    ....
public:
    INJECT(FirstIImpl()) = default;
};

class SecondIImpl : public IInterface {
    ....
public:
    INJECT(SecondIImpl()) = default;
};

Component<A> getAComponent() {
    return createComponent()
        .bind<fruit::Annotated< FirstI, IInterface>,  FirstIImpl>()
        .bind<fruit::Annotated<SecondI, IInterface>, SecondIImpl>();
}
```

Annotated injection is a new feature in Fruit 2.x, I haven't had time to document it yet (sorry). Hopefully the example above should be what you wanted, if not let me know.

If you want to bind the two interfaces to the same type, you'll also have to annotate the implementation class, so that you'll have 2 nodes (objects) in the injection graph instead of 1. E.g.:

```
Component<A> getAComponent() {
    return createComponent()
        .bind<fruit::Annotated< FirstI, IInterface>,
              fruit::Annotated< FirstI, IImpl>>()
        .bind<fruit::Annotated<SecondI, IInterface>,
              fruit::Annotated<SecondI, IImpl>>();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I need. Thanks for your answer, Marco!